# Fetch and update, or create and delete NSManagedObjects in Core Data?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, core-data

I'm just curious and was wondering if there is a "good practice" answer to the following:

If I have a lightweight NSManagedObject subclass in Core Data in which objects will be created and deleted quite frequently and the subclass itself is fairly straightforward (e.g., one relationship, minimal attributes), is it advisable to create and delete instances as needed or to set and unset existing instances as appropriate?

E.g., let's say we have a theoretical NSManagedObject subclass called `Tag` that has a relationship to another subclass `MyObject`. `MyObject` can have many `Tag` objects but each `Tag` has at most one `MyObject` object. `Tag` has one attribute, `text`, which is an NSString set by the user.

In the above case, I can think of two different implementations:

- **Create & Destroy**: When you need a new `Tag`, you create a new `Tag`. When you want to remove a `Tag`, you delete it from Core Data.
- **Update & Reuse**: When you need a new `Tag`, you first search for existing `Tag` objects with `text = nil` and only create a new `Tag` object if all existing `Tag` objects are used. When you want to remove a `Tag`, you remove its relationship to its `MyObject` object and set `text = nil`.

"Create & Destroy" seems more straightforward and takes up exactly as much space as it needs, but "Update & Reuse" minimizes the number of times you delete and create objects. (I would imagine deleting spare `Tag` objects on a `save` and also keeping track of unset `Tag` objects so that you don't have to fetch from Core Data every time.)

Which implementation would you recommend? Is there a different implementation that I haven't thought of? Am I asking the wrong questions / not providing enough details?

I suppose I could make a sample Xcode project and test this out myself, but I'm guessing that you will have a more informed opinion / more experience beyond simply optimizing for time and memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create and destroy is the best practice.  Reuse has implications when your application gets more complex and risks merge problems.  The cost difference between an insert and an update is minimal.